# Sahi controller not working for https sites in Google chrome & IE

Tags: https, ssl-certificate, browser-automation, sahi

When i was trying to navigate to the https:// site from SAHI controller then it was giving some certificate error in chrome/IE browser and I have to click "*Continue to this website (not recommended)."* every time, and after clicking on that it shows the error

```
 This is not a trusted Host.
 Please click on the link below to open page requested by you.

                      Access Page  // this text has link to the given url
```

so that I have created a certificate (ref link :[Create and import certificate](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/8MN333pluGc)) for that site and . 
After that I am not getting certificate error but still I am getting error :

```
 This is not a trusted Host.
 Please click on the link below to open page requested by you.

                      Access Page  // this text has link to the given url
```

And also after coming to this page I am not able to get Sahi controller in both chrome and ie browser.

Info : 
**Chrome version :  38.0.2125.111

IE 10.**

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Revert back the changes that you did. Start Sahi and click on the SSL link present on the Sahi dashboard. Launch a browser through Sahi and go to https://www.google.com

If this opens up correctly, you problem is solved. If not, let me know what happens.

Comment: I followed what you said, but nothing happened, still that error is coming. sahi is working well for other https:// sites but it gives error for only a particular URL. I think it's not certificate error rather something else.

Comment: Is this any internal site of your organization? Also, if you are are using Sahi Pro, you can use their technical support to get a better support for this issue.

Answer (score -1):

if the page is displaying you advance setting option then you can click on it  ,  and click proceed unsafe.

else in beginning where you write URL for Sahipro ,  you can click SSL option.